# Can micelles form in a polar-vacuum interface?

Tags: solutions, surface-chemistry, surfactants

As the formation of micelles depends on, among many factors, the difference of polarity/relative permittivity of the solvents involved with the surfactant, I'm wondering if a polar-vacuum system is possible.

After all, a vacuum has a relative permittivity of 1, the lowest on the dielectric scale. Am I making an incorrect assumption or missing a piece of information in regard to this?

PS: I’m asking from a theoretical framework, not a practical/feasible one.

PS: In regards to the comments asking to define the polar-vacuum system, it is equivalent to the picture micelle; the only difference is that the middle of the normal system is a vacuum, as it has the lowest polarity, even lower than oils.
[image: Micelle Structure]

Comment: Define a polar vacuum system. What systems do you have in mind?

Comment: You cannot have micelles in vacuum.